# 幼稚園 coincidental similarity with english/german?

Tags: etymology

Isn't it a bit strange that it has 園 at the end? Was this word actually made in Japan after they knew about kindergarten ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, according to Wikipedia, 幼稚園 is a direct translation from German "Kindergarten".

> #### [幼稚園](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B9%BC%E7%A8%9A%E5%9C%92)
>
> 幼稚園という語は、彼の作った学校の名前である Kindergarten（フレーベルの造語、「子供達の庭」、「子供の国」の意）を翻訳してできた。
>
> ---
>
> キンダー・ガルテンの訳語として「幼稚園」を最初に名乗ったのが、1876年（明治9年）に開園した東京女子師範学校附属幼稚園で、現在もお茶の水女子大学附属幼稚園として存続し、これが日本で最古の幼稚園とされる。

Related:

- [Is 人孔 from English?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/73358/5010)
- [Calque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calque)

Comment: oh woops i thought that wiki was talking about german to english lol